# Running streamlit with tensorflow causes crash when loading model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, streamlit

When running

```
model = load_model('path_to_model',custom_objects={'my_cutome_activation': my_cutome_activation})
```

Causes a crash

```
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 177, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 358, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 1020, in from_config
    config, custom_objects, 'function', 'module', 'function_type')
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 1072, in _parse_function_from_config
    config[func_attr_name], globs=globs)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 457, in func_load
    code = marshal.loads(raw_code)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Tried upgrading and downgrading `tensorflow` to no avail.

Tried saving the model in the saved-model format which resulted in a different crash:

```
 File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 385, in _load_layer
    metadata = json_utils.decode(metadata)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\json_utils.py", line 69, in decode
    return json.loads(json_string, object_hook=_decode_helper)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\json\__init__.py", line 361, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Works when building the model instead of loading from `hdf5` file.

The model has a custom object as mentioned in the code (custom activation).

Comment: First don't use streamlit, is there a loading problem?

Comment: no problem loading without streamlit.

Comment: There is no trace of streamlit from the crash logs. Are you showing all the logs?

Comment: `File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\dl-gpu\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 475, in _run_script`
no more lines with streamlit mentioned

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7440) it seems like they have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After scanning through the `github` [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7440) posted by @ferdy in the comments (Thanks @ferdy):
Seems to be the following:
Running `tensorflow` by using `streamlit run` invokes a different `serialization` library than when running `tensorflow` in a regular `python interpreter`.
The solution is to write a script to save the model in a streamlit app.

```
import streamlit

model = ...

model.save('streamlit_saved_model')
```

Run the streamlit app once to save the model which will invoke the matching serialization library.

`streamlit run model_saver.py`

Then use this model for the main streamlit app for inference

```
model_streamlit = load_model('streamlit_saved_model', custom_objects={'my_cutome_activation': my_cutome_activation})

model.predict(...
```

`streamlit run model_predictor.py`